# Is the set $\{(x, y) : |y| = |x|\}$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R^2}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces

So, I know that the set $H =\{(x, y) : |y| = |x|\}$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R^2}$, but I wanted to know if the following reasoning was correct:

$|0|=|0|$, and so the zero vector is in the set $H$.

If $(-x,y)$ $\in$ $H$ and $(x,y)$ $\in$ $H$, then $(-x,y)$ + $(x,y)$ = $(0,2y)$ $\notin$ $H$.

If $(x,y)$ $\in$ $H$, then $|x|=|y|$. Thus, $c|x| = c|y|$, and by the absolute value property of the reals, it follows that

$|c||x| = |c||y|$,

$|cx| = |cy|$.

Therefore, $(cx,cy)$ $\in$ $H$.

Since $H$ does not satisfy closure under addition, it is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R^2}$.

Comment: $(-1,1)+(1,1)=(0,2)$, so it is not a subspace.

Comment: Well, I understand that. But, I wanted to know if the other reasoning looks correct?

Comment: The rest of the reasoning is correct, but completely unnecessary. As soon as *one* condition for being a subspace fails, it's not a subspace!

Comment: Again, I understand that. But, I wanted to do that for the sake of improving my proof-writing skills in general.

Comment: Your reasoning is fine, but for the case of non-closure under addition, it is simpler and better form to exhibit a specific counterexample like Eliot did, rather than do it with variables because, e.g. your counterexample fails if $y=0$. I know you realize that, but you don't need to use letters just because it's a proof -- for a counterexample, a specific case with constants is clearer and avoids the trivial counter-counterexample of $y=0$.

Comment: That makes sense, I'll be sure to do that in the future. Thanks

Comment: @K.M Indeed, and it's great to include that in your scratchwork. But one of the things that separates a good proof from an okay proof is clarity and (frequently) conciseness. Including superfluous material hurts readability and should likely be avoided in the final product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is right, but you don't need to say that many things. Your $H$ will fail to be a subspace as long as it fails one of the properties for a single choice of vectors.

So it is enough to say $(-1,1)\in H$, $(1,1)\in H$, $(0,1)=(-1,1)+(1,1)\not\in H$, so $H$ fails additivity and it is not a subspace.